# drupal закэшировал шаблон полностью

Tags: drupal, шаблоны, кэширование

Раньше спокойно редактировал шаблон друпала, а сейчас производимые изменения перестали вступать в силу. Пробовал очищать кэш через админку, вручную очищать таблицы `cache_*` через phpmyadmin, даже переименовал папку `sites/all/themes/theme773/templates` в `templates123`, но сайт даже после этого продолжил нормально работать...

Comment: нормально это ведь хорошо) докрут точно в этот проект смотрит?

Comment: Я так когда-то изуродовал шаблон полностью, пока не понял что это не тот сайт (менял локальный, а смотрел в интернете)

Answer (score 0):

Тоже была такая проблема, решилась путем редактирования файла: "core/core.services.yml".

Установил следующие параметры:

twig.config:
        debug: true
        auto_reload: true
        cache: false

После редактирования нужно отчистить кеш.